# Deterministic / Non-deterministic Stochastic Process

Tags: stochastic, random-process

Problem 6.1-6 of *Probability, Random Variables, and Random Signal Principles, 4th Edition* by Peebles asks

> If a  process is defined by $X(t) = A$, where $A$ is a continuous random variable uniformly distributed on  $(0,1)$,   is 
>   the process deterministic or non-deterministic?

The textbook says that  "a process is called deterministic if its value as a function of time can be pre-determined" and the answer to the
question above is the process is *deterministic.*

My questions are

1. If $A$ is a random variable, then how can we determine time functions (or ensemble members) before specific $A$ is given?
2. What are examples of *non-deterministic processes?*

Comment: Could you please detail the references to your assertion "In Stochastic Process, If process..."?

Comment: yeah, this is a question in 'Probability, Random Variables and random signal principle' by peebles( 4 th edition), problem 6.1-6.

Comment: i will share the pdf as soon as i get

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regardless of what your book might say, a random process is a *collection* of random variables that is described in mathematical notation as
$\{X(t) \colon t \in \mathbb T\}$ or $\{X_t\colon t \in \mathbb T\}$ where
$\mathbb T$ is called the index set (typically, $\mathbb T$ is 
$(-\infty,\infty)$ or $\{\cdots, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, \cdots\}$ or subsets
thereof) and we have one random variable for each $t \in \mathbb T$.
Each random variable is, of course, a mapping from the sample space
$\Omega\to \mathbb R$, and when the experiment is performed and
the outcome $\omega \in \Omega$ is known, the random variable
$X_t$ maps that $\omega$ onto some real number that is, of
course, usually denoted by $X_t(\omega)$.

Now that we have this (typically infinite) collection of random variables,
a *sample path* or *realization* of the random process is the "waveform"
that you see when the experiment is performed (with outcome
$\omega_{11809}$, say) 
and each of the random
variables $X_t$ maps this outcome onto $X_t(\omega_{11809})$.
That's the "waveform": its value at $t = 0$ is $X_0(\omega_{11809})$,
and when $t = 12$, its value is $X_{12}(\omega_{11809})$ and so on.

Now we come to the crux of the matter. A *deterministic* random process
is one for which if we know the value(s) of one or more of the
$X_t(\omega)$, say $X_{0}(\omega)$ and $X_2(\omega)$,
then we know the value of *all* the $X_t(\omega)$: knowing the
value taken on by a few of the random variables in the set tells
us the values that *all* the random variables took on. That is,
there is "no more randomness left" in the process.

With this in mind, consider a random process for which *all* the
random variables $X_t$ are in fact the *same* random variable
$A$. (Whether $A$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$ or not is
totally irrelevant to the issue being considered). Then, if we
know that $X_0(\omega) = A(\omega) = 0.13$, then
we know that $X_t(\omega) = 0.13$ **for all $t \in \mathbb T$**.
That is why your book is claiming that the random process
is deterministic. Note that if $X_t$ were to equal
$A \cos(2\pi f_0 t)$ where$f_0$ is some known constant instead of just $A$,
the process would still be deterministic since knowledge of the
value of $X_0$ would give away knowledge of everything.
If instead $X_t = A \sin(2\pi f_0 t)$, then knowing the value
of $X_0$ would not be useful but knowing the value of
$X_{(4f_0)^{-1}}$ (or any other $X_t$ where $\sin(2\pi f_0 t) \neq 0$)
would again be a telltale.

As a harder question that you can use to test whether you understand
the above explanation, consider whether a random process in which
by $$X_t = A \cos(2\pi f_0 t + \Theta), -\infty < t < \infty$$ where $A$ and $\Theta$
are independent random variables is a deterministic process or not.
Does knowing the values of just a few of the random variables $X_t$
tell you the value of all of them?

So, that is the basic idea behind the notion of deterministic
random processes: observation of *some* part of a sample path
allows us to determine the *entire* sample path with perfect
accuracy. How about nondeterministic random processes? Consider
$$X_n = A_n, \quad n = \cdots, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, \cdots$$
where the $A_n$ are *independent* random variables with some
specific distribution, e.g. each $A_n \sim \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$.
In this case, the process is often referred to as a
(discrete-time) *white noise process* which might give you a
hint as to whether it should qualify as a deterministic or
a nondeterministic process.

Exercise: what is the significance of the number 11809 in the second
paragraph above?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done if you know how to create a Cantor set using sinusoids with discreet frequencies. In other words, the answer is no, you cannot present a regular ranom process with deterministic functions.